# R ggplot2 for loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I am trying to do to a for loop in ggplot, where I am replacing a variable that should indicate the name of existing variables that subset the data

Here is the loop, but I get an error:

```
list1=c("name1","name2",...)
list2=c("name1","name2",...)

for (name in 1:2) {
g=ggplot(data=data[paste("data$MEPS %in% list",name,sep=""),], 
     aes(x=Year, y=RR, colour=MEPS, group=MEPS 
       ))+
geom_line()+geom_point()+scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100, 10))+
print(g)
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error in seq.default(h[1], h[2], length = n) : 
'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
```

This seemed like it should be easy -- basically I want to graph line graphs where each graph includes the information for certain areas named in `list1` or `list2`

**EDIT:** To clarify, what this code is "supposed" to do is produce two ggplot objects, one that has 3 lines, and the other that has 2 lines. The 3 lines represent items I wanted to show that are %in% list1, and the same thing for list2. That's whay the confusion here.

Comment: This is probably easier to achieve by defining a new factor variable in your dataframe that maps MEPS to listx. Then try using that variable as a group.

Comment: Can you exlpain this better? I'm new to R and while your answer may be good I'm not sure I know what I need to do based on it.

Comment: Hi, if you have to id that way, then you should  evaluate your expression like this **data=data[eval(parse(text = paste("data$MEPS %in% list",name,sep=""))),]**

Comment: I tried doing that but I still got the same error......thoughts?

Comment: Hi, can you add this **drop=FALSE** just like this : **data=data[eval(parse(text = paste("data$MEPS %in% list",name,sep=""))), , drop=FALSE]**

Comment: Actually the first line you provided worked! Here is the final solution:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code provided by @Mamoun Benghezal worked really well!

```
for (name in 1:2) {
png(paste("plot",name,".png",sep=""),width=800, height=600)
g=ggplot(data=data[eval(parse(text = paste("data$MEPS %in% list",name,sep=""))),],
     aes(x=Year, y=RR, colour=MEPS, group=MEPS))+
geom_line(size=.8)+scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 100, 10))+labs(y="Response Rate")+
coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 100))
print(g)
dev.off()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example as a prototype to approach your problem. We have the `mtcars` data and want a line plot of mpg versus wt for each country of origin.

I could loop through countries and select the German cars, plot them, then the the Japanese and so on.  Instead I define a new factor for the country and assign based on the `row.names`. Using the group aesthetic, ggplot will go ahead and plot this with a separate line for each country. Not a great visualiztion of this particular data, but it does give you a prototype to follow.

```
data(mtcars)
mymtcars<-mtcars

mymtcars$country<- c(rep("JP",3),rep("US",4),rep("DE",7),rep("US",3),"IT",rep("JP",3),rep("US",4),"IT","DE","UK","US",rep("IT",2),"SE")

ggplot(mymtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, group=country)) + geom_line(aes(colour=country))
```

Comment: Thanks @vpipkt, but what if I wanted to plot "DE" and "US" cars together as two separate lines in one plot, and then do antoher that had "IT" and "JP" as two separate lines in another plot? That was the issue i was having.